# Match tables using 2 criteria in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I just begin coding in R , I am trying to manipulate data but I have an issue which is the following:
I have 2 different tables (simplified )
the first one (`player_df`) is as follows:

```
 name   experience      Club        age       Position 
 luc          2         FCB         18        Goalkeeper
 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
 ronaldo      14        FCB         32        Goalkeeper
 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
 messi        11        Liverpool   35        midfielder
 tevez        6         Chelsea     27        Attack
 inzaghi      9         Juve        34        Defender
 kwfni        17        Bayern      40        Attack
 Blabla       9         Real       25        midfielder
 wdfood      11        Liverpool   33        midfielder
 player2      7         Chelsea     28       Attack
 player3     10         Juve       34        Defender
 fgh         17        Bayern      40        Attack
...
```

The second table is the salary by club and experience in million (`salary_df`)

```
*experience    FCB   BAYERN    Juve   Real  Chelsea 
1               1.5   1.3     1      4      3
2               2.5   2       2.4    5      4
3               3.4   3.1     3.5    6.3    5
4               5     4.5     6.7     9     6
5               7.1   6.9     9      12     7
6               9      8      10     15     10
7               10     9      12     16     15
8               14     12     13     19     16
9               14.5   17     15     20     17
10              15     19     17     23     18
..*
```

I would like to add a new column to my data in the first table named let say `salary_estimation`, and which takes into consideration 2 variables for example here `experience` and the `club`.

For example for "luc" who plays in "FCB" and has "2" years experience the output should be "2.5"

In excel its an index / match function, but in R I don't know which function should I use .

How should I approach the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Data:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = 'name   experience      Club        age       Position 
 luc          2         FCB         18        Goalkeeper
                 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
                 ronaldo      14        FCB         32        Goalkeeper
                 jean         9         Real        26        midfielder
                 messi        11        Liverpool   35        midfielder
                 tevez        6         Chelsea     27        Attack
                 inzaghi      9         Juve        34        Defender
                 kwfni        17        Bayern      40        Attack
                 Blabla       9         Real       25        midfielder
                 wdfood      11        Liverpool   33        midfielder
                 player2      7         Chelsea     28       Attack
                 player3     10         Juve       34        Defender
                 fgh         17        Bayern      40        Attack', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df2 <- read.table(text = 'experience    FCB   BAYERN    Juve   Real  Chelsea 
1               1.5   1.3     1      4      3
                  2               2.5   2       2.4    5      4
                  3               3.4   3.1     3.5    6.3    5
                  4               5     4.5     6.7     9     6
                  5               7.1   6.9     9      12     7
                  6               9      8      10     15     10
                  7               10     9      12     16     15
                  8               14     12     13     19     16
                  9               14.5   17     15     20     17
                  10              15     19     17     23     18', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Code:**

```
library('data.table')
setDT(df2)[, Chelsea := as.numeric(Chelsea)]
df2 <- melt(df2, id.vars = "experience", variable.name = "Club", value.name = "Salary" )
df2[df1, on = c("experience", "Club"), nomatch = NA]
```

**Output:**

```
#    experience      Club Salary    name age   Position
# 1:          2       FCB    2.5     luc  18 Goalkeeper
# 2:          9      Real   20.0    jean  26 midfielder
# 3:         14       FCB     NA ronaldo  32 Goalkeeper
# 4:          9      Real   20.0    jean  26 midfielder
# 5:         11 Liverpool     NA   messi  35 midfielder
# 6:          6   Chelsea   10.0   tevez  27     Attack
# 7:          9      Juve   15.0 inzaghi  34   Defender
# 8:         17    Bayern     NA   kwfni  40     Attack
# 9:          9      Real   20.0  Blabla  25 midfielder
# 10:         11 Liverpool     NA  wdfood  33 midfielder
# 11:          7   Chelsea   15.0 player2  28     Attack
# 12:         10      Juve   17.0 player3  34   Defender
# 13:         17    Bayern     NA     fgh  40     Attack
```

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions is by joining first table (let say it is `player_df`) with "long format" of second table `salary_df` using `experience` and `club` as keys. You can do it by using `tidyverse` package.

```
library(tidyverse)

player_df %>%
  mutate(Club = str_to_title(Club)) %>%
  left_join(
      salary_df %>% 
        pivot_longer(-experience, names_to = "Club", values_to = "salary_estimation") %>%
        mutate(Club = str_to_title(Club)) )

# Joining, by = c("experience", "Club")
# # A tibble: 13 x 6
#    name    experience Club        age Position   salary_estimation
#    <chr>        <dbl> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>                  <dbl>
#  1 luc              2 Fcb          18 Goalkeeper               2.5
#  2 jean             9 Real         26 midfielder              20  
#  3 ronaldo         14 Fcb          32 Goalkeeper              NA  
#  4 jean             9 Real         26 midfielder              20  
#  5 messi           11 Liverpool    35 midfielder              NA  
#  6 tevez            6 Chelsea      27 Attack                  10  
#  7 inzaghi          9 Juve         34 Defender                15  
#  8 kwfni           17 Bayern       40 Attack                  NA  
#  9 Blabla           9 Real         25 midfielder              20  
# 10 wdfood          11 Liverpool    33 midfielder              NA  
# 11 player2          7 Chelsea      28 Attack                  15  
# 12 player3         10 Juve         34 Defender                17  
# 13 fgh             17 Bayern       40 Attack                  NA
```